# Proof $\lim_{n \to \infty} a_n = 0$ for $a_{n+1} \leq qa_n$

Tags: limits, analysis, proof-writing

Let $(a_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ be a sequence of real numbers with $a_n \geq 0$ for all  $n \in \mathbb{N}, q \in [0,1), N_0 \in \mathbb{N}$ such that

$$a_{n+1} \leq qa_n$$

for all $n \geq N_0$.

How can one prove that $\lim_{n \to \infty} a_n = 0$?

I know that $\lim_{n \to \infty} a_n = \infty \Leftrightarrow \lim_{n \to \infty} a_n^{-1} = 0$, but I don't know how to prove that $\lim_{n \to \infty} a_n = 0$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fix $N_{0}$ and $q\in\left[0,1\right)$. For $n= N_{0}$ and $k\in\mathbb{N}$ you have $a_{n+k}\leq q a_{n+k-1}\leq q^{2}a_{n+k-2}\leq\dots q^{k}a_{n}$.

\begin{align}
0\leq \lim_{m\to\infty}a_{m}=\lim_{k\to\infty}a_{n+k}\leq a_{n}\lim_{k\to\infty}q^{k}=0
\end{align}

Answer (score 1):

Prove by induction that

$$0 \le a_{N_0+k} \le q^ka_{N_0}$$

for all $k \in \mathbb N.$

Can you proceed ?